# Magento 2 - How to create a calculator

Tags: magento2, php, xml, wamp

I've created a new module in magento 2 and I want to add some additional files so that I can create a calculator. I'm unsure where to create a file that calls the functions of my calculator class and where I can pass data into the functions.

Say I have a php file as follows, what would be my code and where would I be creating the file so that I can all these function?.

```
<?php 

namespace Mage\Calculator\Model; 

class Calculator{ 

public function divide($x, $y) 
{ 
    return $x/$y; 
}

public function multiplication($x, $y) 
{
    return $x*$y;
}

}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Put that functions in a block instead model, then you can call them in your phtml like this : `echo $block->divide($x, $y)` or `echo $this->divide($x, $y)`

Block path `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Block/Name.php`

Comment: So like this, <h2><?php $this->divide($x,$y);?></h2>  ?

Comment: Yes, why not but with some `echo` it's better :) , ensures that you create well your block and the phtml should be in the same module

Comment: ok, try first to display some string then check if you get it well `public function divide() 
{ 
    return "hellllo"; 
}`